# Getting smooth transitions using scrollTop()

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I am trying to slightly do away with our fixed header on our university website and have come up with a way I think would work great for those with smaller screens and yet still please those individuals that like having the header available no matter where they are on the page.

It's kind of hard to explain my issue so here is a link to an example:
http://codepen.io/daless14/pen/smdou

Code:

```
$('body').prepend('<div class="show-menu">MENU</div>');

$(window).scroll(function(){  
  if ($('.header').is(':hover')) { 
    $('.header').css('top', '0px');
  }
  else if ($(this).scrollTop() < 85) { 
    $('.header').css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': '0px'}); 
    $('.header-content').fadeIn(100);
  }
  else if ($(this).scrollTop() > 85) {
    $('.header').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '-85px'});
    $('.header-content').fadeOut(100);
  }
});

$('.show-menu').click(function() {
  $('.header').animate({'top': '0px'},150);
  $('.header-content').fadeIn(400);
});
```

The header has an absolute position until the window scrolls past 85px and it then sticks to the top and a little menu button appears. If the user is on a lower part of the screen they can click "Menu" to make the header slide down to become visible. My only issue is that when the user scrolls again (if they're not hovering over the header element) the header should slide back up. Currently it just "jumps" back up.

I added in a CSS transition to the header element that fixes it but makes other areas break.

Just curious if anyone has any ideas on how to make this smooth.

Thanks!

Comment: CSS transition is pretty much the only way I see that makes sense for this, unless you want to do the choppy slow jQuery `.animate()` method (which may or may not break things less). You'll obviously need to elaborate on what breaks with the CSS transition solution, and look into that. Cool UX though. I like what you did with the site.

Comment: Which part of your if statement runs in the scenario you speak of when the user scrolls again - if it's the last `else if` statement have you tried slowing the `fadeOut` of your `.header-content`. 100 miliseconds is very fast. Fading is different to sliding as well `slideOut(400)` unless i'm getting your question muddled

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When adding in a CSS transition, the header does slide up/down as it should but glitches at the top when the user first scrolls past that 85px mark and also when the user scrolls back up past the 85px mark. Here's an example: http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/uojki

Answer (score 0):

When you call fadeOut of header content, it seems to have no sense, because header is not visible on page already. So I guess you should try to do fadeOut first and hide header next, something like this.

```
$('.header-content').fadeOut(200, function(){
   $('.header').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '-85px'});
});
```

Comment: sorry, yeah the fadeOut is not necessary. It's actually only there because I wanted 5px of the header element to stick out but there are elements in the header that would normally stick out past that point. That is just there to fade out the content in the header so it doesn't look awkward with little bits of content showing when the header element is up. Hope that makes sense!